# Is there a way to make a game splitscreen in BGE

Tags: python, scripting

I want to make a 2 player game but I need it to use 2 cameras. Sorta like an fps. I'm not great with code, any help?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this thing can help you
https://youtu.be/78ORdi4-ynk

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?261732-Split-Screen-in-the-BGE

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help. Also python code out dates very fast.